# Vagrant support for Type 1 Hypervisor

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-vcenter, vagrant, hypervisor

I need to be able to spin up VMs every now and again so that I can have a space to build the latest iteration from my project's 'dev' branch (using chef), run the configuration scripts, and make sure that the scripts are not broken due to the latest build changing something.

I've been looking at Vagrant and I like what I see so far, but it seems from the website to favor Type 2 Hypervisors. After some googling and poking around the mailing list, I found that there is a vSphere plugin on github aside from the baked-in VirtualBox support.

My question is, does Vagrant have support for a T1 Hypervisor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Vagrant KVM provider](https://github.com/adrahon/vagrant-kvm) exists which uses libvirt for controlling the hypervisor. Thus it (in theory; I don't know if the provider implements it yet) can be used to deploy either to the local workstation or a remote hypervisor.

A [Vagrant libvirt provider](https://github.com/pradels/vagrant-libvirt) exists which provides more general provisioning via libvirt, and thus could (again, in theory) be used to provision VMs on any libvirt-supported hypervisor, such as KVM, Hyper-V, ESXi, etc.

Comment: vagrant-kvm and vagrant-libvirt both use libvirt and both only support KVM. vagrant-libvirt can be used to control VMs both locally or remotely, whereas vagrant-kvm only works locally.

Comment: @sciurus Time for somebody to add the features then :)

Comment: [From vagrant-kvm README](https://github.com/adrahon/vagrant-kvm): "This project is dead, please use [vagrant-libvirt](https://github.com/pradels/vagrant-libvirt/) instead!"